# awstats do not show statistics from IIS 8.5

Tags: windows, perl, iis, awstats

awstats 7.7 do not show the statistics. Iam using IIS 8.5.
I configured site logging as follow in IIS in W3C format:

- date
- time
- c-ip
- cs-username
- cs-method
- cs-uri-stem
- sc-status
- sc-bytes
- cs-version
- cs(User-Agent)
- cs(Referer)

Logfiles are located here

```
C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1
```

Logfiles will be created daily.
Example:

```
2018-08-29 05:18:25 GET /ping/ping.php - 10.74.20.182 HTTP/1.1 Mozilla/5.0+(Windows+NT+6.1;+WOW64;+rv:43.0)+Gecko/20100101+Firefox/43.0 http://sbs20websrv01.sb.edeka.net/ping/ 200 252
```

My config file looks like this:

```
LogFile="C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\*.log"
LogType=W
LogFormat=2
LogSeparator=" "
SiteDomain="sbs20websrv01.sb.XXX.net"
HostAliases="localhost 127.0.0.1 REGEX[myserver\.com$]"
DNSLookup=2
DynamicDNSLookup=0
DirData="C:\inetpub\wwwroot\stats\"
DirCgi="/stats/cgi-bin"
DirIcons="/stats/icon"
AllowToUpdateStatsFromBrowser=0
AllowFullYearView=2
EnableLockForUpdate=1
DNSStaticCacheFile="dnscache.txt"
DNSLastUpdateCacheFile="dnscachelastupdate.txt"
```

Whats wrong?

Comment: I edited the config to my Lofiles to LogFile="C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex%YY-24%MM-24%DD-24.log". But now iam getting the following error: Error: Couldn't open server log file "C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex180828.log" : Permission denied 

Setup ('C:\inetpub\wwwroot\stats\cgi-bin/awstats.sbs20websrv01.sb.edeka.net.conf' file, web server or permissions) may be wrong.
Check config file, permissions and AWStats documentation (in 'docs' directory).

Answer (score 0):

Logfile path have to look like this:

```
LogFile="C:\inetpub\logs\LogFiles\W3SVC1\u_ex%YY-24%MM-24%DD-24.log"
```